# SRX FW configuration

Tags: firewall, juniper-network-connect

Try configure SRX FW , try set static arp

> [edit interfaces ge-0/0/3 unit 0 family inet address 10.1.1.1/24]
>
> ```
> user@host# set arp 10.1.1.3 mac 01:ff:85:7f:78:03
> ```

return :

> ```
>      Invalid unicast address at '01:ff:85:7f:78:03'
> ```

Why is this invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Solved , happened IP is a Cluster IP which is Multicast mac 
as simply say "mac" JunOS assumed unicast which is invalid

So say "multicast mac" and should be OK

Fun

Regards
Brian